# MySQl Unique Count based on multiple factors

Tags: mysql

I need to count distinct hits for my website based on ip's and category.

I am able to count distinct ip's but not able to get distinct categories. I have around 250 categories.

I am doing this way.

My table structure.

```
 |id | category  |     ip     |    date    |
 | 1 |    234    | 1698170031 | 1457966671 |
 | 2 |    234    | 1698170032 | 1458041287 |
 | 3 |    233    | 1698170033 | 1458041298 |
 | 4 |    233    | 1698170034 | 1458041334 |
 | 5 |    102    | 1698170035 | 1458042584 |
 | 6 |    102    | 1698170036 | 1458042614 |
 | 7 |    102    | 1698170037 | 1458042865 |
 | 8 |    102    | 1698170038 | 1458043089 |
 | 9 |    102    | 1698170039 | 1458043171 |
 | 10|    102    | 1698170040 | 1458043181 |

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `total` FROM `stats`.`hits`;
//this is working fine showing 10 hits 

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `hits` FROM `stats`.`hits` GROUP BY `category`;
//this is not working showing 1 hit 

//expected result
category 234 = 2 hits
category 233 = 2 hits
category 102 = 6 hits
```

I also know another way to get distinct category hits

```
//adding to main query
.
.
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `category` = '234' THEN `ip` END) `234`,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `category` = '233' THEN `ip` END) `233`,
.
.
```

but it will be very long query

Please suggest a way around to get DISTINCT category counts.

Thanks

Comment: what is your current result and your desire result? At first glance the query looks ok.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have mentioned that in question, please see

Comment: As I said looks ok too me.. I run it on my postgres server.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/xJezO.png

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
SELECT 
category,
COUNT(DISTINCT ip)
FROM
hits
GROUP BY category;
```

like you already tried. This does not return just 1 row. You messed something up, I don't know, but this is the solution.

Proof (but too lazy to format nicely):

```
root@localhost:playground > CREATE TABLE t
    ->     (`id` int, `category` int, `ip` int, `date` int)
    -> ;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `category`, `ip`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 234, 1698170031, 1457966671),
    (2, 234, 1698170032, 1458041287),
    (3, 233, 1698170033, 1458041298),
    (4, 233, 1698170034, 1458041334),
    (5, 102, 1698170035, 1458042584),
    (6, 102, 1698170036, 1458042614),
    (7, 102, 1698170037, 1458042865),
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

root@localhost:playground >
root@localhost:playground > INSERT INTO t
    ->     (`id`, `category`, `ip`, `date`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     (1, 234, 1698170031, 1457966671),
    ->     (2, 234, 1698170032, 1458041287),
    ->     (3, 233, 1698170033, 1458041298),
    ->     (4, 233, 1698170034, 1458041334),
    ->     (5, 102, 1698170035, 1458042584),
    ->     (6, 102, 1698170036, 1458042614),
    ->     (7, 102, 1698170037, 1458042865),
    ->     (8, 102, 1698170038, 1458043089),
    ->     (9, 102, 1698170039, 1458043171),
    ->     (10, 102, 1698170040, 1458043181)
    -> ;
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

root@localhost:playground > SELECT
    -> category,
    -> COUNT(DISTINCT ip)
    -> FROM
    -> t
    -> GROUP BY category;
+----------+--------------------+
| category | COUNT(DISTINCT ip) |
+----------+--------------------+
|      102 |                  6 |
|      233 |                  2 |
|      234 |                  2 |
+----------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a loop (I'm going to use PDO notation)

```
$query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM stats");
$query->execute();
while ($category = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$countquery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN category = :category THEN ip END");
$countquery->bindParam(':category', $category);
$countquery->execute();
echo "(results of query here)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `hits` FROM `stats`.`hits` GROUP BY `category`;

//this is not working showing 1 hit

it needs small modification

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) FROM table_name GROUP BY `category`;

+----------------------+

| COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) |

+----------------------+

|                    6 |

|                    2 |

|                    2 |

+----------------------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)